# Java Forms connecting with eacother in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Im working on an app which lets the user plan a menu (this is a school project), and I ran into the problem that when i plan the menu, and the duration is 7 or longer it connects the first and seventh, second and eight etc forms with eachother and if i fill in one of them it automatically fills the other. I tried many things, but nothing seems to be working.

This is the Activity, which handles the populating of the RecyclerView:

```
public class NewMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String usrname;
    String name;
    Date startDate;
    int duration;
    private final List<MenuClass> formDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MenuAdapter adapter;
    private List<Calendar> formDates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_menu);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        usrname = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        startDate = (Date) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("startDate");
        duration = intent.getIntExtra("duration", 0);

        formDates = calculateDates();
        setupFormDataList();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new MenuAdapter(formDataList, formDates);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);


        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Upload data to Firebase
                uploadDataToFirebase();
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadDataToFirebase() {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Menus").child(usrname);

        for (int index = 0; index < formDataList.size(); index++) {
            MenuClass formData = formDataList.get(index);
            Calendar formDate = formDates.get(index); // Get the corresponding date

            // Format the date to a string (you can choose your desired date format)
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(formDate.getTime());

            Log.d("Firebase_Upload", "Index: " + index);
            Log.d("Firebase_Upload", "Date: " + dateString);
            Log.d("Firebase_Upload", "formData: " + formData.toString());

            // Create a child node with the date as the key
            DatabaseReference childReference = reference.child(name).child(dateString);
            childReference.setValue(formData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Data uploaded successfully
                        Log.d("Firebase_Upload", "Data uploaded successfully");
                    } else {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.e("Firebase_Upload", "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private List<Calendar> calculateDates() {
        Calendar initDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        initDate.setTime(startDate);

        List<Calendar> formDates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            Calendar formDate = (Calendar) initDate.clone();
            formDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
            formDates.add(formDate);

            // Log the calculated date for debugging
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Log.d("CalculateDates", "Date " + i + ": " + dateFormat.format(formDate.getTime()));
        }

        return formDates;
    }

    private void setupFormDataList() {
        formDataList.clear(); // Clear any existing forms
        for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            MenuClass menu = new MenuClass();
            formDataList.add(menu);
            Log.d("FormDataList", "Adding data: " + menu.toString());
        }
        Log.d("NewMenuActivity", "formDataList size: " + formDataList.size());
    }


//    for (MenuClass mc : ){

//    }
}
```

And this is the code of the Adapter, which handles the editing of the said forms:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<MenuClass> data;
    private List<Calendar> formDates;

    public MenuAdapter(List<MenuClass> data, List<Calendar> formDates) {
        this.data = data;
        this.formDates = formDates;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MenuClass formData = data.get(position);
        Log.d("DataObjectHash", "Data object hash code: " + System.identityHashCode(formData));

        // Attach TextWatchers to capture user input and update formData
        holder.etName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                formData.setName(s.toString());


                Log.d("UserInput", "User input: " + s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });

        holder.etSpecial.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                formData.setSpecial(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });

        holder.etIngredients.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                formData.setIngredients(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
        Calendar dateCalendar = formDates.get(position);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(dateCalendar.getTime());
        holder.dateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText etName, etSpecial, etIngredients;
        TextView dateTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            etName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            etSpecial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etSpecial);
            etIngredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etIngredients);
            dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using ListView, with the same error, and tried logging stuff, or modifying the code, but nothing seems to help.

This picture shows little, but first i filled out 2023.11.11 but 11.18 got filled with the same data:
[image: the problem]